# android getting null pointer exception at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm reading writing string arrays and displaying them in recycler view.
Before displaying them i'm reversing the order using 
    Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(FilePathStrings));
  Following is exception that I'm getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:3826)
at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:3813)
at com.example.soberapps.nightcamera.b.c.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.i.b(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.o.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.o.e(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.o.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.c.d(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.o.b(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.o.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.o.b(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.o.h(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.o$1.run(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.a(Interrogator.java:19)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:164)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:156)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:34)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.a(MotionEvents.java:75)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.a(MotionEvents.java:50)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.c(Tap.java:8)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.a(Tap.java:18)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.b(Tap.java:3)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:22)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:9)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:78)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:94)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:3)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6316)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

Error reporting crash

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1689)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1636)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerProxy.java:5217)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:97)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1068)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1063)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.asList(null)` throws this exception. Your parameter (`FilePathStrings`) equals to null.